How to recover from Auth0 Errors
I have Auth0 working effectively in my React app. Now, I am trying to track down edge cases to recover/respond when users hit errors. I see that useAuth0 returns an error. But I don't see a list of the potential errors it can return or recommendations for how to respond to the different errors.
Is a list of the possible errors. And is there guidance for handling errors returned from useAuth0?
Here is what I have:
import {useAuth0} from "@auth0/auth0-react";

export const onAuthError = async (error: Error, isAuthenticated: boolean, logout: (options?: LogoutOptions) => Promise<void>) => {
    errorService.notify(error); //This is my error tracking.
    localStorage.clear();
    //clear other things as needed
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        await logout();
    }
    if (window.location.pathname !== "/login") {
        window.location.href = "/login";
    }
};

const MyApp = () => {
    const {isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently, user, isLoading, error, logout} = useAuth0();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
            onAuthError(error, isAuthenticated, logout);
        }
    }, [error]);
};


Common Auth0 Library Authentication Errors
